# Counting unique values in Google Spreadsheet based on multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, unique

Let's take this spreadsheet for example:

```
ID | StoreName | StoreID | CheckinTime  | User
0  | w1        | 1       | 10:00        | user1
1  | w5        | 1       | 10:01        | user2
2  | w2        | 1       | 10:01        | user1
3  | w1        | 1       | 10:01        | user4
4  | w5        | 1       | 10:05        | user1
5  | w3        | 1       | 10:05        | user6
6  | w1        | 1       | 10:05        | user1
7  | w1        | 1       | 10:05        | user1
```

Is there a way to create a new column/tab/sheet to count all the unique checkins for a store. So let's say; StoreName "w1" is visited by "user1" 3 times and 1 time by "user4". The expected output will be 2 (2 unique visitors for "w1"). This is the output I would like to have:

```
ID | StoreName | uniqueCheckins
0  | w1        | 2
1  | w2        | 1
2  | w3        | 1
3  | w4        | 0
4  | w5        | 2
```

Comment: Are you able to explain the ID column in your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce the StoreName and uniqueCheckins output columns:

`=QUERY(QUERY(B:E,"select B, E, count(C) group by B, E",1),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'uniqueCheckins'",1)`

However this will omit any StoreName that doesn't appear in the raw data (in your example, w4). Would this be OK?

Comment: Great, thanks! Unfortunately I'm not sure how to implement this. Let's say I want a new tab in my spreadsheet with the desired output described in my startpost. Which columns do I need to add and where to put the query? I'm sorry but I'm new to this kind of queries

Comment: I tried to add it in my spreadsheet but I did not manage to get it work. I created an example spreadsheet here, can you show me (it's editable) how it's done? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pLx3FfuZuw5nf9gx14JSQYe2caWBNahmLs0ZuTAJHhM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `=QUERY(QUERY(Checkins!A:D,"select A, D, count(B) where A != '' group by A, D",1),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'uniqueCheckins'",1)`

Comment: I actually still don't see what I'm doing wrong in this spreadsheet. Still getting an error:
https://docs.google.com/a/fanly.nl/spreadsheets/d/1JL185Xk7aquOD6MXRnD837Z1FA2XlYLOQJor7iD-2Xo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `=QUERY(QUERY(CheckIn!F2:H;"select F, G, count(H) where F != '' group by F, G";1);"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'uniqueCheckins'";1)` - couple of issues with your formula, but the main one is that your locale (Netherlands) demands use of semi-colons as argument separators, rather than colons.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is it also possible to count without the ID column (H)? In my working sheet I've got 6000+ records (no column H), is it possible to count on the storename string?

Comment: And another question; is it possible to output the storeId behind/before the name of the store on the new tab?

Comment: The count(x) can be any column you wish - what is in that column is irrelevant, in this case. You could use `...CheckIn!E2:G;"select F, G count(E)...`

Comment: And for the second question, just make sure your range reference includes the columns you require, and then name those columns in the `select` (in any order you wish).

Answer (score 1):

Updated my answer

```
=({FILTER(SORT(UNIQUE(Index(UNIQUE({B2:B,E2:E}),,1))),SORT(UNIQUE(Index(UNIQUE({B2:B,E2:E}),,1)))<>""),ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(INDEX(UNIQUE({B2:B,E2:E}),,1),"="&FILTER(SORT(UNIQUE(Index(UNIQUE({B2:B,E2:E}),,1))),SORT(UNIQUE(Index(UNIQUE({B2:B,E2:E}),,1)))<>"")))})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What is the best way to populate a table like my example output?

Comment: Can you explain the ID column?

Comment: I made a mistake while creating this example sheet. ID is in my case just the rownumber

Comment: Try the updated Formula. Also Unless you enter the store names manually, you can only get the stores in the list, for obvious reasons.